# the Angular CLI command: ng generate module flat true doesn't work

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

```
ng generate module file.module.ts flat=true
```

the above command should create a module, not a module inside a folder of the same name.  However, it doesn't work for me.  It always creates the folder and places the .ts file in it.

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
ng generate module test --flat
```

This will generate a module named test.module.ts in your current directory

Comment: same result, it generates a folder and places the module.ts file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

The flag should be used like this: --flat=true. So, the following works fine (at least for me - Angular CLI:16.2.11):

`ng g m material --module=app --flat=true`